# Safari creates Zero bytes instead of actually downloading files

Tags: macos, safari

Each time I <kbd>Cmd+S</kbd> an .mp3 or .mp4 file, it saves it, but as it turns out, as an empty Zero bytes file. Even if I'm explicitly choosing Save As and Format=Page Source, it doesn't work. I doubt this is an expected behaviour as it has let me down several times since some of the files are no longer online.

This issue is very similar to [After Maverick, Safari will not download PDF files](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5619001), but the solution there doesn't work for me as I don't even have that "Allow Plugins" checkbox in my version, nor do I use any.

I have Safari 11.0.3 on Mac OS Sierra 10.12.6

This is very frustrating. Please help

Comment: What happens with right click, 'Download linked file as...' ? Save As... is to save the web page as an archive, not really to download files linked from within it.

Comment: @Tetsujin the file isn't linked to from anywhere, I'm on it's page already. Please go to http://kcrw-od.streamguys1.com/kcrw/audio/website/music/mb/KCRW-morning_becomes_eclectic-latest_show-180511.mp3 for an example. P.S. I understand right now I can right click and save as from within this comment

Comment: That's not designed to be downloaded, it's designed to stream. The workaround is right click 'save video as'

Comment: @Tetsujin which I did and still got the Zero bytes :(

Comment: Maybe try a downloader... iGetter is shareware & has a decent interface & safari integration [it's never going to be a replacement for Speed Downloader, but I guess nothing is] - otherwise, I'm out of ideas, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the same problem again, googled my own question.

As it turns out, *where exactly you right-click* makes a difference. I happened to be doing it on a progress bar, and that gave me the "*Save Page As*" option, which results in zero-bytes downloads. However, if you right-click **the timer** or **the controls**, it gives you a whole other dropdown with some media-related options, one of them being *Download Video As*, which works properly.

So the answer is:

- <kbd>Cmd+S</kbd> won't work;
- pay attention where you click and make sure you save via the media content-related dropdown.